# Why does unpacking a struct result in a tuple?

Tags: python, struct, tuples, pack, unpack

After packing an integer in a Python struct, the unpacking results in a tuple even if it contains only one item. Why does unpacking return a tuple?

```
>>> x = struct.pack(">i",1)

>>> str(x)
'\x00\x00\x00\x01'

>>> y = struct.unpack(">i",x)

>>> y
(1,)
```

Comment: If the struct contains more than one item then what do you return?  Generally, it's best if functions return only a single type (so the caller doesn't have to special case depending on whether there is one item or two or ...)

Comment: I see...Is this the only/correct/Pythonic way to pack/unpack an *int*?

Comment: In more recent python versions there is `int.from_bytes` and `int.to_bytes`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please see doc first [struct doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#functions-and-exceptions)

> struct.pack(fmt, v1, v2, ...)
>
> Return a string containing the values
> v1, v2, ... packed according to the given format. The arguments must
> match the values required by the format exactly.

--

> struct.unpack(fmt, string)
>
> Unpack the string (presumably packed by
> pack(fmt, ...)) according to the given format. The result is a tuple
> even if it contains exactly one item. The string must contain exactly
> the amount of data required by the format (len(string) must equal
> calcsize(fmt)).

Because `struct.pack` is define as `struct.pack(fmt, v1, v2, ...)`.
It accept a non-keyworded argument list (`v1, v2, ...`, aka `*args`),
so `struct.unpack` need return a list like object, that's why tuple.

It would be easy to understand if you consider pack as

```
x = struct.pack(fmt, *args)
args = struct.unpack(fmt, x)  # return *args
```

Example:

```
>>> x = struct.pack(">i", 1)
>>> struct.unpack(">i", x)
(1,)
>>> x = struct.pack(">iii", 1, 2, 3)
>>> struct.unpack(">iii", x)
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I should have mentioned in my question that I saw this in the docs. I'm not sure ***why*** it returns a tuple though...

Answer (score 2):

Think of a use case that loads binary data written using C language. Python won't be able to differentiate if binary data was written using a struct or using a single integer. So, I think, logically it makes sense to return tuple always, since struct pack and unpack perform conversions between Python values and C structs.